# Why does meld get stuck on my remote 3-way comparison?

Tags: remote, diff, mobaxterm, meld

I'm running a 3-way merge using meld (via git mdiff actually) - on a remote machine. My own machine is Windows 10, and the remote machine is Devuan GNU/Linux Chimaera.

While the meld window does come up with the 3 files, there's a "loading" kind of UI indication on the meld toolbar, and the file contents is grayed out. After 5 minutes - nothing has changed. I should mention the files are not very long - under 1,500 lines. On the Windows machine, I'm using mobaxterm with its X server.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Since you're doing this on Windows, I suspect the answer will be on the Windows side and the network latency. I suggest you delete this and ask on [su] instead.

Comment: @terdon: TBH, I doubt that's the issue, since high latency would just mean response would be slow, and that's not what I complained about. But - if nobody answers, I'll move my question there.